# Reacting to Bluetooth Disconnection

Tags: bluetooth, 7.0-nougat, tasker, automation, samsung-galaxy-s7

I have a problem where disconnecting from various bluetooth devices switches my phone into Silent Mode. This is causing me to miss important calls and messages. There are quite a few different devices that I connect to and disconnect from throughout the day (car, headphones, bluetooth adapter connected to stereo, etc.)

It's being suggested to me that Tasker might be a solution to this issue. But I don't see that Tasker can be set up to listen for bluetooth disconnection events. Can anyone help me with this?

Basic goal is to listen for any bluetooth disconnection event. When such an event fires, I want to switch the Sound Mode to 'Sound'. Can this be done?

I'm using Android 7.0 on a Galaxy S7.

Comment: I don't know Tasker. Try this with another automation app [Macrodroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid)  Trigger : Blue tooth disconnect > any device ; Action: Priority mode > none

Comment: Another action can be Volume change and configure slider scales to what you want

Answer (score 0):

You can use Tasker to accomplish this, but since we need a *bluetooth disconnect* as *event* instead of *state* we need to create a dummy entry
task then move the actual task to exit so that it corresponds with bluetooth disconnect event.

**Profile Context**

- Go to Profiles Tab and click the "+"
- Event ➡ State ➡ Net ➡ [BT Connected (Name: name of BT device, Address:Input MAC address of BT device)] *For multiple devices don't input anything in these fields*
- Tap back to exit from this window

If using BT name seems not to be working try using the MAC address of BT device instead.

**Entry Task**

You will notice as soon exit, you will be prompted to link this to a Task
 Here we just create a Task wait action as dummy

- Scroll all the way up the Task list select "New Task + "
- You can just keep it anonymous or give it a name
- Click "+" to add new Action
- Task ➡ Wait  ➡ 4 seconds
- Tap back all the way until you exit this task

**Exit Task**

- Create a new Task (name it anything)
- Click "+" to add new Action
- Audio ➡ Silent mode: Set Off
- Tap back to exit from this task

Once you're done, Tasker should now automatically turn off Silent mode upon disconnection (exit) from your selected Bluetooth devices.