# How to use Events in Tasker?

Tags: applications, bluetooth, tasker

I clicked on Profiles + Event and selected the event that I want (Net > bluetooth connection) and it shows me two input fields with Name and Address and a list of variables above.
Ok I select the variable that I want, but how do I give it a condition/value? If I enter anything else than the variable name it gives me some error about lower case characters...

Basically I want an event that matches `if(%bt_name="Some device Name" && %bt_connected=true)` and there's nowhere I can enter such code!

I find it baffling that there's no single example on the entire Internet about how to use this Tasker feature!

Comment: This [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/179896/131553) should help